# LED in recessed fixture occasionally dims

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

My house was built in 2011 with 6 recessed fixtures in the kitchen ceiling. I replaced the original incandescent lights with CFLs first then LEDs. I replaced the CFLs after one light went out. The same fixture (which now has a LED) will occasionally dim. I have replaced the bulb and removed the insulation around the can but I still get an occasional dim light. It will not go back to full strength until after being off for some time. These lights are not on a dimmer. Has anyone had this issue before? 
Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks,
Charles

Comment: Is the fixture getting hot inside when the dimming happens?

Comment: > I replaced CFL with LED after one light went out > One light is still out *Just pointing out this isn't an LED problem, it's a preexisting problem and switching to LED had no effect*

Comment: Thank you for the comments, as far as I can tell, the fixture is not getting hot. When I removed the bulb, I did not notice any excessive heat.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I believe you are correct. Although, the CFL I replaced was a cheapo brand and it had worked fine for about a year (if my memory is correct). Also this is the second LED I had in this can neither of which started dimming immediately (at least a few months for both). I hate problems that I cannot replicate consistently.

Comment: Unlikely, but it might be powerful RF interference at the fixture (e.g. near a diathermy machine or a radio transmitter). Another possibility is heat from a stove or vent fan, or a water leak above the fixture.